# How can we use AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer to render CMSampleBufferRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, cmsamplebufferref

I have this delegate method

```
-(void)airPlayServer:(id)server sampleBufferReceived:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
}
```

which gives me `sampleBuffer`.

Now I need to know how can I use `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` to render my sampleBuffer.  I know we have to use - `enqueueSampleBuffer` - but I am new to iOS so how can we do it?

I don't want to convert sampleBuffer to CGImage and then draw it.

Code example is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
   CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = ...;

    // Force display as soon as possible

    CFArrayRef attachments = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBufferRef, YES);
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0);
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);

    [sampleBufferLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBufferRef];            
    [sampleBufferLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```